Source port random assignment by windows operating system
I am new to TCP/IP and trying hard to learn basics. When I was using wireshark, I noticed that the source port of my application keeps on changing.  Some of my colleagues shared that this is a normal behaviour whereby the operating system will keep changing the source port numbers.  Any kind hearted personnel share the reason?
I was expecting that the source port to be fixed at coding level based on my observation at the wireshark.


I was expecting that the source port to be fixed at coding level

The source port can be explicitly fixed at the coding level using bind(). But this is usually not done, since this would result in unnecessary possible conflicts in the ports used between applications, and also between multiple sockets inside the same application.
That's why the choice of source port is usually left to the underlying OS, which picks a (more or less random) port from a range of ephemeral ports which are not in use.

Hi @Steffen Ullrich, noted with thanks.  Do you happen to know why OS does not fixed a value for the source port number from the range of ephermeral ports?

@HeahMinyi: Why should the OS use a fixed value? It just makes things more complicated (on what base the source port should be choosen to avoid conflicts with other apps) without having any actual gain?

Think of a situation where a computer has multiple connections to the same server (for example, a web browser or database maintaining a connection pool). If all the connections used the same source port, they wouldn't be able to be connected to the same server port at the same time. Each TCP connection is uniquely identified by a tuple of Protocol + Source IP/Port + and Destination IP/Port. So, if the Protocol and Destination are the same, the Source must be different. Clients don't usually fix their Source Port unless required to do so by protocol or external (ie, firewall, etc) restrictions.
